# XPath with two conditions

Tags: xpath

I want to select the `div` with class `"bmBidderButtonText"` and with `"Low"` as inner text, what should I do?

```
   <div class="bmBidderButtonText"><div class="bmBidderButtonArrow"></div>Low</div>
<div class="bmBidderButtonText"><div class="bmBidderButtonArrow"></div>High</div>
```

Merely `//div[@class="bmBidderButtonText"]` will select two divs, but how should I include the "Low" as inner text as condition within the xpath?

Comment: `... and .='Low'`

Comment: @william007 is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.` to reference current context element, so implementing additional criteria of ***"...and with 'Low' as inner text"*** in XPath would be as simple as adding `and .='Low'` in the predicate of your initial XPath :

```
//div[@class="bmBidderButtonText" and .="Low"]
```

**<kbd>[`demo`](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/-u07RXCtB)</kbd>**

Answer (score 1):

Try this below `xpath`

```
//div[@class='bmBidderButtonText'][text() ='Low']
```

**Explanation:-** Use `class` attribute of `<div>` tag along with the `text` method.

Comment: Have you try this code? Does my explanation of code `helped` you?

Answer (score 0):

use `and`:

```
//div[@class="bmBidderButtonText" and contains(., "Low")]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `contains()` for this reason:

> //div[contains(text(), 'Low')]

***Additional resources:***

- [Choosing Effective XPaths](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/choosing-effective-xpath/)